# Android: управление ПК на Windows

Tags: java, android, windows, клиент-сервер

Как я могу организовать удаленное управление ПК с помощью устройства на Android? Например, включение музыки, открытие браузера и т.п.

Как проще организовать серверную часть на ПК. А именно, как после получения команды от клиента выполнять соответствующие действия в ОС Windows?

Comment: Например подключаться по сокетам :) использовать RMI. Конкретизируй вопрос. Очень обширно

Comment: Смотря какие действия вы хотите выполнять. Для включения браузера хватит обыкновенного `System.getRuntime.exec()`. Если хотите ответов - опишите более конкретно ваше видение клиента, сервера. И с чем конкретно у вас проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Написать сервер, который будет крутиться на "ПК" и написать клиент для Андроида.